# Cannot position floating elements correctly

Tags: html, css

So I'm a little beginner somewhat in CSS, I've been trying to achieve this shape (excluding colors, background colors etc. For now, not a problem yet) So basically I have 3 sections and I want each section to have a title for it on the top right corner (always at top-right) never to change position even if other elements shift/move, so I'm trying to achieve as shown in this picture exactly.[Module I'm trying to get to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHAkO.png)

And this is what I've gotten to so far [My Module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WwmN.png)

Here's the HTML code and CSS after the body element and the styles applied to it (Note: try to widen the window after running the code so the styles are applied, it will be applied after 992 pixels wide)

https://jsfiddle.net/62hsernc/4/

```
/*The Desktop Version*/

@media (min-width: 992px){
    *{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
h1.header {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
      text-align: center;
}



span {
    border: 1px solid black;
    float:left;
    margin: 20px;
    
}

.sectionheader1, .sectionheader2, .sectionheader3{
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 40%;
    float:right;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    padding: 1px;
    margin: 0px;

    
    
}

.row{
    width: 100%;
}

    .col-lg-4{
        float: left;
        width : 33%;
        margin: 1px;

    }
}
```

**NOTE:** What I'm mainly trying to achieve is to be able to control the `span` (the dummy text ) individually without affecting the position of `H1` or anything related to `h1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply `position: relative` to the `span` and `position: absolute` to the `h1`, positioning it with `top: 0` and `right: 0` at the top right, and use `padding-top` in the span to create the space for it.

(note: I removed your media query in my snippet to make it work in the snippet window here)

```css
/*The Desktop Version*/

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1.header {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

span {
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
  margin: 20px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 40px 10px 10px;
  background: #efefef;
}

.sectionheader1,
.sectionheader2,
.sectionheader3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 40%;
  min-width: 120px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1px 5px;
  background: #fba;
  margin: 0;
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
}

.col-lg-4 {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
  margin: 1px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1 class="header">CSS-Module Header</h1>


  <div class="row">
    <section class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">

      <span><h1 class = "sectionheader1">Chicken</h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut sagittis sit amet lorem id feugiat. Morbi eu velit sit amet dui ultricies cursus. Sed tempus tellus id nisi vehicula eleifend vel in libero. Duis faucibus enim ac augue luctus lacinia. In condimentum odio in mi efficitur volutpat. Mauris non tristique est.</span>
    </section>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This is pretty good but I need to be able to control the paddings of the span only and not have the H1 affected by it, this still give me the same exact problem, I want to control spacings and colors and paddings of the dummy paragraph and the title won't get affected

Comment: So the dummy text inside span is what I'm trying to control individually, without having any affects/movements on the h1 tags, I can control paddings and colors of H1 tag but since span is the ancestor it keeps inheriting its stylings to the h1, so for example if i add paddings to the span element the H1 tag is moving with it, that's not what I want. I want to move the dummy text separately, you get what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Note: I changed my answer completely corresponding to my last comment and edited the  code accordingly.

Comment: This is seems do-able, just an additional question am I suppose to keep randomly changing px value for the offsets till the h1 gets to where I want it to be? is there any easier way I can tell the exact values I need to position it where I want?

also is this going to be a fixed position? meaning if elements move, will the h1's move with it?

Comment: Again not sure what you mean. "Offsets..."? - I thought you want it in the top right corner? If not, change the `top` and `right` parameters. BTW: It's not `fixed` position, but `absolute` position - this uses the parent element which has `position: relative` as a position anchor, so when the parent moves, the absolutely positioned child will move with it.

Comment: I was trying to do the absolute and relative but I was a bit confused as to how to achieve that, could you explain further the absolute positioning ? I know that for relative even though you change its position visually, its position originally is still considered there, for absolute positioning I'm not entirely sure

Comment: As I wrote before: An absolutely positioned element uses the next higher ancestor (parent) element  as a position anchor which has `position: relative`. top/bottom/left/right, width/height relate to the parent in this case. When the parent moves, the absolutely positioned child will move with it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I appreciate it. I was in desperate need to find a solution for my problem for some time and have been brainstorming so long and couldn't fix it, so again thank you so much

Answer (score -1):

Try putting position:fixed; I' m not sure if it will work, but try it anyway!